How to close off shell and create watertight mesh
I have a shell that was created from a photogrammetry scan of an object. I want to essentially create a set of faces that closes off the object and creates a watertight mesh for printing and further modeling.
The mesh looks like this, kindof a bulbous leaf. I have tried some sculpting solutions with limited success. I also tried to select all the vertices on the rim and create faces, but maybe there is a trick?


Essentially I want to create this face below, as shown by intersection with a plane


You might want to rephrase your question to avoid phrases like "What is the best way," as it can make the question seem opinion-based, which is off-topic. Instead, try to make it as objective as possible by describing how you are currently solving the problem and where you are getting stuck. This way, the community can better understand your issue and provide more targeted and helpful solutions.

Thanks @HarryMcKenzie rephrashed a little and also added some other description/ideas
